# I have to use something (this case notepad++) and regex to find and redact/clean email addresses - can't find a good regex for this

Tags: regex, email, logging

I have tried many regex expressions in notepad++ (need to scrub log files up to several hundred thousand lines long) and this one is doing the best job:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

but it is missing an email on a line that has a space first. Part of the problem is I am using notepad++ as it is available in our restricted environment.
sample log entry:

```
    and orgid = 'OFMC' and worktype = 'DM' and historyflag = 0 and siteid <> 'IA TEST' and wonum like '%08'
blahken.mun@test.com
 ken.mun@test.com
[3/17/23 7:04:05:041 EDT] 00000001 ODCConstructo 
ken.mun@test.com
jeff.kish@mytech.com
[3/17/23 7:04:05:108 EDT
```

But it only found these 3 and not this with a leading space( ken.mun@test.com):

**blahken.mun@test.com**
**ken.mun@test.com**
**jeff.kish@mytech.com**

Comment: You only want to match email addresses when they are not surrounded by other text on the same line?

Comment: *"I have tried many regex expressions"*: are they of your own hand? Do you understand what this regex does?

Comment: I guess the simple answer is to put a space in front of your regex `^<here>([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9] ...`

Comment: There is the woefully inadequate html5 email regex you can use http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address

Comment: Here is a US version RFC5322 `/(?im)^(?=.{1,64}@)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"@)|((?:[0-9a-z](?:\.(?!\.)|[-!#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^\`\{\}\|~\w])*)?[0-9a-z]@))(?=.{1,255}$)(?:(\[(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|((?:(?=.{1,63}\.)[0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9])|((?=.{1,63}$)[0-9a-z][-\w]*))$/`

https://regex101.com/r/Z9OwjW/1

Comment: This is International (Unicode) version RFC5322 `/(?im)^(?=.{1,64}@)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"@)|((?:[\pL\pN](?:\.(?!\.)|[-!#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^\`\{\}\|~\w])*)?[\pL\pN]@))(?=.{1,255}$)(?:(\[(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|((?:(?=.{1,63}\.)[\pL\pN][-\w]*[\pL\pN]*\.)+[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN]|-){0,22}[\pL\pN])|((?=.{1,63}$)[\pL\pN][-\w]*))$/u`

https://regex101.com/r/PsvM36/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using notepad++ you could match optional leading horizontal whitespace chars `^\h*` and then use `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

If you don't need all those capture groups, and you want to match either an ip like number between optional paired up square brackets or chars a-zA-Z0-9 and -

```
^\h*\K[\w.-]+@(?:(\[)?\d{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}(?(1)])|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ezj5DW/1)

Comment: I modifed this one by the fourth bird and it works in an apparently improved manner:  ^\h*\K[\w.-]+@(?:(\[)?\d{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}(?(1)])|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$